# Select data from JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file with the dataset below:

```
[
    {
        "key": {
            "domain": "mail_1.com"
        },
        "data": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "area": "yey",
                    "number": "2000",
                    "Name": "Maria",
                    "Username": "Maria2",
                    "ID_nb": "11228169"

                }
            ]
        },
        "class": "1.1"
    },
    {
        "key": {
            "domain": "john.com"
        },
"data": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "area": "house",
                    "number": "4000",
                    "Name": "John",
                    "Username": "John22",
                    "ID_nb": "1124562"
                }
            ]
        },
        "class": "1.3"
    }
```

From this JSON file, I am trying to create a new JSON file with each key:domain and corresponding data:array:area and data:array:number
It should give something like:

```
[
    {
        "key": {
            "domain": "mail_1.com"
        },
        "data": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "area": "yey",
                    "number": "2000"
                }
            ]
        },

    {
        "key": {
            "domain": "john.com"
        },
"data": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "area": "house",
                    "number": "4000",
                }
            ]
        }
```

Can you please help me ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: So can you formulate the problem you're tryng to solve? Get python dict from JSON string? Process python dict from one format to another?

Comment: Just creating a python dict from this JSON only with the data I am interesting in, which is the domain, area and number and removing the rest.

Comment: @Broc You will have two options create a new json and another option is deleting the keys from the json you don't need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to remove "Name", "Username" and "ID_nb"

```
with open('path_to_your_file.json') as jf:
     js = json.load(jf)
     for elem in js:
         elem['data']['array'][0].pop('Name', None)
         elem['data']['array'][0].pop('Username', None)
         elem['data']['array'][0].pop('ID_nb', None)
```

The 'None' from pop is just to return nothing instead of exception if there is no element element with that name to pop

Comment: My issue is that I would like to select domain as well as area and number (domain is not in the same array)